# Simultaneous execution of cron in NestJS

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, nestjs

I'm using NestJS' Task Scheduling - but all the Crons are getting executed twice simultaneously.

My guess is that it is happening because they are getting triggered on all instances of the server.

Is there any workaround to fix this? Without having to change any server-related settings.

Comment: As you said, I have only a "workaround". What I did was upon starting all instances, allow to create 1 Mongo record in DB. If it's successful (due to being unique), then it's master instance and only it is allowed to execute cron jobs.

Comment: Are you using clustering or scaling the system horizontally or doing both?